# xacro dependency problem while installing gazebo_ros_pkgs on ROS Groovy

Tags: catkin, xacro, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm running **ROS Groovy** on **Ubuntu 12.04**, and I'm trying to install **Gazebo 1.9** from sources, as explained in the [online tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages) on the official wiki.

I can clone the repos (including *ros_controllers*) and update rosdep without problems, but when I get to

```
rosdep check --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR[joint_trajectory_controller]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [xacro]
    rosdep key : xacro
    OS name    : ubuntu
    OS version : precise
    Data: <no data>
```

Looking around for solutions, I found out [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/63302/cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-joint_state_publisher/) that the problem is probably that xacro is a dry (rosbuild) package and so it cannot be referenced from a catkin package.

If I ignore the error and go on, after a `catkin_make` I get

```
Set xacro_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for xacro. 
The file will have one of the following names:

xacroConfig.cmake
xacro-config.cmake
```

Can you suggest any way of dealing with this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4253/xacro-dependency-problem-while-installing-gazebo_ros_pkgs-on-ros-groovy/) by [micpalmia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/473/micpalmia/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try the `groovy-devel` branch, it's currently the same as `hydro-devel` but without `gazebo_ros_control`.

```
git clone -b groovy-devel https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git
```

Alternatively, try checking out a copy of `xacro` in your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) on 2013-09-04**:
gazebo_ros_control is slated for release in hydro, so @hsu's suggestion is a good one. If you are still interested in giving the hydro stuff, use a recent version of rosdep to resolve missing dependencies.

**Comment by [micpalmia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/473/micpalmia/) on 2013-09-04**:
I first removed the references to xacro to build anyway, today I removed the package and downloaded it again using your solution and it worked. Thanks!